# Wordpress development/production sites in parallel

Tags: wordpress

I have a production Wordpress site, but in parallel I want to run a development site. Once I am done with the development, I want to deploy it to the production site without ruining the current site regarding, users, comments, etc. 
My current solution is to duplicate the production site, and re-install again- but than I can lose information. 
Did not find any solution that can do it. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a wordpress-theme/plugin, you can just dump the live-db, replace the domain and use it in development. After you finished developing, you can dump it again, insert/update your content for production, deploy only your theme and replace the db of your production environment with the one of your dev-environment

Comment: yes. the problem I have in this mechanism, that if the DB has been modified meanwhile (e.g. there is a new comment), it will be lost. Is it so?

Comment: after you finished developing you can just deploy your changed files without the database. This way you will not lose data.

Answer (score 0):

If your site has already go public, things will be more complex. I suggest you setup a maintenance mode and then dump the db to development site.

If you are developing theme/plugins, you can just upload the theme/plugins files. Leave the data in the dev site.

If you are modify the site through wp-admin(change theme/plugins settings), you have to upload the db data.You don't need to dump all data, for example, you don't need to dump the dev site's comment data and import to production site. But this way, you must know WordPress database schema very well.

Always, backup your site before you do any changes.